# How to start Putty in a maximized window?

Tags: window-management, putty

How to start Putty in a maximized window in Ubuntu 12?

When I use Windows, [I use this method](http://my.kualo.com/knowledgebase/887-how-to-start-putty-in-a-maximized-window.html)

But in Ubuntu, I don't have this option.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something on the functionalities of Putty, but why would you need Putty on Ubuntu (or any other Linux)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Apparently you cannot enlarge the initial (configuration) window with `-geometry`.
- Also the `-geometry` setting is ignored if it is overwritten by the terminal size in Putty.

Actually the most convenient form to specify the size of the Putty window is by using the Putty configuration.  You can have different default settings by giving them with the `-load` option on the commandline.  See below.

Following settings can be changed which affect the size of the resulting Window:

- `Font` (Category :: Window :: Fonts) by using another size

[image: Fonts settings from the Debian GNU/Linux version of Putty, on Ubuntu it's similar]

- Window `Columns` and `Rows` (Category :: Window)

[image: Columns and Rows setting - from the Windows version, but likewise on Unix]

If you only need a single setting, do it as follows:

- Start Putty
- Click on `Session`
- Click on `Default Settings`
- Click on `Load`

Then edit the above settings to your needs.  Afterwards do not forget to save it via:

- Click on `Session`
- Click on `Default Settings` (or, for additional settings as explained below, enter the name of the configuration you want to save in the textbox above `Default Settings`)
- Click on `Save`

Now if you open Putty the next time, enter the `Host Name` and click `Open` the altered `Default Setting` will be loaded and give your Screen the chosen size.

By copying this `Default Setting` to some small/medium/large setting, you can even have different defaults active when loading Putty.  All you have to do is to leave blank the `Host Name` in these additional defaults.  Then start it as follows, from shortcuts or commandline:

```
putty -load small HOST
putty -load medium HOST
putty -load large HOST
```

Leave `HOST` away if you want to enter it into Putty.  (If you leave away the `-load XXX` then Putty will use `Default Settings`).

If you save some configuration with a `Host Name` preset, and saved under `HOST1` for example,

[image: Actually the screenshot is from the Windows version of Putty, but under Unix it works the same]

you can start this session directly from commandline by loading this configuration:

```
putty -load HOST1
```

You can re-use this saved session as a template and override the `Host Name` as well from commandline, as follows

```
putty -load HOST1 another.host.example.com
```

HTH

PS: Sometimes Putty is just a bit too straight forward to be easily understood ;)

Comment: Note about the windows screenshots: I am posting this with Win7, so taking suitable screenshots from Windows was faster.  The Windows "Fonts" settings is under "Appearance".

Answer (score 1):

You can start `putty` with `-geometry` option. For example:

```
putty -geometry 1000x1000 hostname
```

Comment: And what is hostname? Is my user in Ubuntu?

Comment: @VitorMazuco Lol, you should ask what is a hostname before to ask this question. What for do you use putty? The hostname should be the host name or IP address where you connect. See `man putty` for more info.

Comment: Ok appear ~$ putty -geometry 5000x5000 x.x.x.x
The program 'putty' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.The error was 'BadAlloc (insufficient resources for operation)'.(Details: serial 213 error_code 11 request_code 53 minor_code 0) (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously; that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)

Comment: @VitorMazuco Do you see in my answer 5000x5000?

Comment: Ok, but when I use 1000x1000 thw window appear tiny, nothing change.

Comment: @VitorMazuco Use maximum your screen resolution.

Comment: How can I discover my maximum screen resolution?